# approach to save multiple address in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

[addressform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QXjq.png)
I have to store address in database should i create 21 column to save data of each textfield of address. if user check the delivery address and invoice address to be same in that case redundant data is saved.i just want to know good approach to save the data.

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: please click on formpage

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/relational-database-for-address-model

Comment: please add more detail to your question , its not clear for auditors

Answer (score 1):

Create a table `addresses` with 7 attribute columns and a primary key column. It is traditional to use an auto-increment integer for the primary key.

Create a table for your form data with three integer columns. These integers reference the primary key of the `addresses` table. You may set these three columns to the same integer value, if the order, invoice, and delivery addresses are the same. Or they may have two or three different values.

This way you don't store the address details more than once. You only store the integer that references them.

This way of organizing data is what relational databases are all about. It's referred to as database normalization. The principle is to reduce redundant data.